Calculation of effective mass of electrons from energy dispersion relation for electrons
Given the energy dispersion relation for electrons, $ \epsilon_{k} = \beta(cosk_{x}a + cosk_ya + cosk_za)$ , I want to find out the effective mass of electrons at the boundary of the first Brilloin zone that is at $k_x=k_y=k_z=\pi/a$. Here $\beta$ is a constant and $a $ is the lattice spacing.
For that purpose I calculated the the second order partial derivative of $\epsilon_k$ w.r.t. $k$ .
$\partial\epsilon_k \over\partial k$ $=\beta$ $\partial \over \partial k$ $(cosk_{x}a + cosk_ya + cosk_za)$
$\partial \over \partial k $ $(cosk_x a)$ $=$ $\partial \over \partial k_x$ $(cosk_xa)$ $\partial k_x \over \partial k$.
$k = \sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2+k_z^2}$
$\partial k \over \partial k_x$ $=$ $k_x \over \sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2+k_z^2}$ $=$ $k_x \over k$.
Hence, $\partial k_x \over \partial k$ $=$ $k \over k_x$.
So, $\partial \over \partial k $ $(cosk_x a)$ $=$ $-a$ ($sink_xa$) ($k \over k_x$)
Then, proceeding similarly I calculated the first order partial derivatives w.r.t. $k$ of $cosk_ya$ and $cosk_za$ and from there I calculated their respective second derivatives w.r.t. $k$.
Ultimately I found the value of $\partial^2\epsilon_k \over\partial k^2$ at $k_x$ $=$ $k_y$ $=$$k_z$ $=$ $\pi\over a$.
$\partial^2\epsilon_k \over\partial k^2$ $=$ $9\beta a^2$.
Effective mass $=$ $m^*$ $=$ $\hbar^2 \over{\partial^2\epsilon_k \over\partial k^2}$
or,   $m^*= {\hbar^2\over{9\beta a^2}}$
But this is not the value of $m^*$ I am supposed to get. The correct value of $m^*$ is $\hbar^2\over{3\beta a^2}$.
I have made some mistake in calculating $\partial^2\epsilon_k \over\partial k^2$ for the given energy dispersion relation.
I am unable to spot where I have made the mistake.
I would be very much thankful for helping me in this regard.

Are you sure that quoted answer is correct? Here is my result:
The effective mass is actually a (symmetric) tensor given by:
$$ (M^{-1})_{ij} = \frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial^2\epsilon}{\partial k_{i}\partial k_{j}}  $$
For the dispersion $$ \epsilon_{k} = \beta(\cos{k_{x}a} + \cos{k_ya} + \cos{k_za})$$
there are no terms containing different momenta directions and each 2nd derivative is identical so we have:
$$(M^{-1})_{ij} = -\frac{\beta a^2}{\hbar^2} \cos{k_{i}a}\, \delta_{ij}$$
or written as a matrix
$$
M^{-1} = -\frac{\beta a^2}{\hbar^2}\begin{pmatrix}
\cos{k_{x}a} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{k_{y}a} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cos{k_{z}a} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
At $k_{x} = k_{y} = k_{z} = \frac{\pi}{a}$, using $\cos{\pi} = -1$ we have:
$$M^{-1}(k_{x} = k_{y} = k_{z} = \frac{\pi}{a}) = \frac{\beta a^2}{\hbar^2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{\beta a^2}{\hbar^2}I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Thus the inverse (effective mass tensor) is:
$$M(k_{x} = k_{y} = k_{z} = \frac{\pi}{a}) = \frac{\hbar^2}{\beta a^2}I
$$
So the effective mass is isotropic and has a value of $m^* = \frac{\hbar^2}{\beta a^2}$
